# Why does VSC say Import "pygame" could not be resolved

Tags: python, pygame

I am using pygame for the first time but when i try to import it to VSC it says Import "pygame" could not be resolved does anyone know why this is and how to resolve it?

```py
import pygame
import sys
import random
```

Comment: how are the other two imports relevant to the particular question?

Comment: I just put the other part for completeness.

Comment: @muzeD1, have you installed the `pygame` module?

Comment: Where can I install it on VSC

Comment: it's not the VSC, it's your Python installation. check this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pygame-in-windows/

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure that when you downloaded python, you enabled "Add python to PATH". If not, reinstall it, but make sure to enable "Add python to PATH" this time. Once installed, to test if you installed it without an error, open the command prompt by searching "cmd" in the search bar. Then, write "python" and hit enter. If it doesn't return an error, try:

```
pip install pygame
```

If that doesn't work:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

Past that, if that doesn't work, that might mean that you installed python incorrectly, once again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PyGame first.

After opening VSC, go to the terminal tab <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> and type

```
pip install pygame
```